# Unable to get listPreference to work in Android

Tags: android, listpreference

I tried searching for an answer on here and on Google but didn't manage to get very far.

I'm trying to do a `listPreference` on the Android platform allowing users to choose their text colour. Currently it's only returning the default value and I'm not quite sure why my if/else statement isn't working.

prefs.xml:

```
    <ListPreference
    android:title="textcolorpreference"
    android:key="list1"
    android:summary="Text Color"
    android:entries="@array/list"
    android:entryValues="@array/lValues"
    />
```

array.xml:

```
     <string-array name="list">
    <item>Red</item>
    <item>Green</item>
    <item>Blue</item>
    <item>Yellow</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="lValues">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    </string-array>
```

Java:

```
    SharedPreferences getPrefs =
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());


        String values = getPrefs.getString("list", "2");

        if(values.contentEquals("1")){
            tp.setColor(Color.RED);
        } else if(values.contentEquals("2")){
            tp.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        } else if(values.contentEquals("3")){
            tp.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        }else if(values.contentEquals("4")){
            tp.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }
```

Currently only the default value of the list preference works e.g. if I put the listPreference default values a `String values = getPrefs.getString("list", "2")` I get `color.GREEN` which makes me think I need to add a preference changed listener, but I'm currently unable to implement it.

I'd be extremely grateful for any help you guys are able to provide !

Comment: You have `android:key="list1"`, but you're calling `getString("list"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the correct Integer from the prefecence **list1**

```
Integer values = getPrefs.getInt("list1", 2);
```

then you could switch from the values retrieved:

```
switch(values ) {
    case 1:
        tp.setColor(Color.RED);
        break;
    case 2:
        tp.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        break;
    case 3:
        tp.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        break;
    case 4:
        tp.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        break;
    default:
        tp.setColor(Color.GREEN);
}
```

Comment: StarsSky, you're a lifesaver!